# how do i delete a value from an array in java that is linked to a .jar file?

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, jar, nullpointerexception

the items array is declared in the jar and its size and value is decared by me.i tried this

```
public void itemsDelete(int x)
{
    Item[] temp=new Item[items.length-1];
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    {
        if(i!=x)
        {
            temp[i]=items[i];
        }
    }
    items=new Item[temp.length]
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    {
        items[i]=temp[i];
    }
}
```

and a if(items[i]!=null){code...}
but in both cases when i run it this "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException ""is seen.what could be the problem?

Comment: You ***could*** just do `items=temp`, you know. A list would be a much better data structure to use for this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop will alway stop before it copies the last item, and also there will not be any value copied into the temp array at index x.

Imagine items is an array of Strings:

"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"

And you want to delete the item at index 5 with that code you would get:

"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", null, "6", "7"

Which might explain why you get a null pointer exception, presumably later when the items array is processed.

This might do more what you want, and, as Perception suggested, you can just assign items equal to temp when you are done.

```
public void itemsDelete(int x)
{
Item[] temp=new Item[items.length-1];

//This variable will keep track of the index in the temp array
int j = 0;

//for each of the items in the input array...
for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
{
    if(i!=x)
    {
        temp[j]=items[i];
        //We've copied a value so increment the temp index...
        j++;
    }
}

items = temp;
}
```